# How to connect to my personal computer with my router's public ip?

Tags: ssh

I try to connect to my remote computer through ssh. I have a public IP address that I found from [whatismyip.com](/www.whatismyip.com/) but I can not connect to it.

I can to ping the IP address. I believe that this public IP is from the router and not from the computer.

Any ideas on how to connect to the computer? or how to get its public IP?

Comment: Your remote computer is behind a router? Is this a domestic router that does NAT too? If so you need to port forward.

Comment: Yes, the remote computer is behind a router, I am not sure the router does NAT, I have no access to it, I will try to forward the port

Comment: I have forward the port 3389 to the local IP of one of my computer, but if I try another port it doesn't work, do you know which other port can I use for another computer behind the same router

Comment: Why would you forward port 3389 (Remote Desktop) when you want to connect with SSH (port 22)?

Comment: The router doesn't allow me to forward port 22, it says it is reserved for SSH

Comment: So I just can cotroll 1 computer behind the router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup Port Forwarding on your router. Just look for page with similar name on router's setup page.
In this particular case you need to forward External 22 port to your PCs local IP port 22.

Comment: I have forward the port 3389 to the local IP of one of my computer, but if I try another port it doesn't work, do you know which other port can I use for another computer behind the same router

Comment: You are connecting External Router inbound ports to any of your local PCs inbound ports.
Your ISP may block some ports. You can try ask your ISP which inbound ports are allowed to use.